# Flex loads Flash SWF with Popup

Tags: flash, apache-flex, popup, modal-dialog

My Flex application is required to load a SWF file externally. This SWF file has a popup. How could I ensure the popup is at the middle of my Flex application and modal?

Thanks.

**Edit:**
The popup component is owned by SWF file (through a "Show more" button) and is not just an Alert. The SWF file is provided by third party. Any update on the SWF file and its popup component do not require re-compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new component let's say MyExternalPopup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Box>
    <mx:ModuleLoader url="YourExternalSWFHere.swf"/>
</mx:Box>
```

and then you can show and center the popup like this:

```
var popup :IFlexDisplayObject = PopUpManager.createPopUp( Application.application, MyExternalPopup );
PopUpManager.centerPopUp( popup );
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Added more info: The popup component is owned by SWF file (through a "Show more" button).

Answer (score 0):

You may find that the Alert class does what you want.  If not, you're probably better off listening to the swf for an event and then responding to the event on the Flex side by popping up the dialog.

Comment: The popup is not just a Alert class. The popup component is from the swf and not from my Flex application.

Comment: Try looking at globalToLocal, if there is a hard necessity to do it from the swf.